# ByVal in Excel event-handler

Tags: vba, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I am a little confused about the usage of `ByVal` keyword in some event-handlers in Excel.

**The NewSheet event example** 
(Copied from *Excel 2019 Power Programming with VBA*, Wiley)

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If TypeName(Sh) = "Worksheet" Then
        Sh.Cells.ColumnWidth = 35
        Sh.Range("A1") = "Sheet added " & Now()
    End If
End Sub
```

This code works as expected, as seems trivial. But after some thought I am getting more and more confused.

Based on my understanding `ByVal` means `Sh` is just copy of the the original worksheet object, and procedures using `ByVal` arguments won't result in change to the original object. In other words, what the code does should have no effect.

Only when references are passed to procedures will they be able to modify objects referred to by those references.

Am I missing something there? Thanks

P.S. Most of my understanding of passing by reference/value comes from other programming languages such as C#. There might be some peculiarity in VBA I am not aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're passing an Object, ByVal passes a copy (the value) of the reference. The copy (value) of the reference still points to what the original reference is pointing to.  Hence your method works and changes what the original reference is pointing to.

If you know Java, this is similar in nature to Java, where everything can be said to 'pass by value' but when you pass an Object as a parameter, what you are actually doing is passing a copy of the reference, and not a copy of what the reference is pointing to.

Comment: YES. How did I forget this? I don't know Java, but C# essentially has the same concept. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnSmithSr. it's actually the same concept in all languages. `ByVal` never clones/copies any object.

Answer (score 0):

ByVal in those cases prevents the change of the value in the original reference itself.

Please see next:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        ' Declare an instance of the class and assign a value to its field.
        Dim c1 As New Class1()
        c1.Field = 5
        Console.WriteLine(c1.Field)
        ' Output: 5

        ' ByVal does not prevent changing the value of a field or property.
        ChangeFieldValue(c1)
        Console.WriteLine(c1.Field)
        ' Output: 500

        ' ByVal does prevent changing the value of c1 itself. 
        ChangeClassReference(c1)
        Console.WriteLine(c1.Field)
        ' Output: 500

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Public Sub ChangeFieldValue(ByVal cls As Class1)
        cls.Field = 500
    End Sub

    Public Sub ChangeClassReference(ByVal cls As Class1)
        cls = New Class1()
        cls.Field = 1000
    End Sub

    Public Class Class1
        Public Field As Integer
    End Class
End Module
```

Comment: Thanks, Aiyuni reminds me of the concept too. Nice snippet.

Comment: Note: this is VB.NET code; OP is asking about VBA - same principles apply though.